# MySQL PHP Between variables

Tags: php, mysql

So my HTML is

```
 <form action="payScale.php" method="POST">
   Pay Scale Starting Range: <input type="text" name="start">
    <br>
    Pay Scale Ending Range: <input type="text" name="end">
    </form>
```

and my php is

```
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT s.skill_Description, s.skill_PayRate from harris.SKILL s where s.skill_PayRate between'  'and'   '";

$query = $query."'".$start."';";
```

and I have no idea how to use the two variables of start and end.  how do i format the end of the select statement and the the line below it incorporating the two variable start and end?

Comment: You only have one variable since you used `$start` for both.

Comment: sorry it's meant to be end i'll change it

Comment: Rather than a text field, you should be using a drop down menu so you can control the type of salary ranges you are getting. If you let the user type it, how will you format it?

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using `$_POST` (or any user input) directly in queries.  I recommend using PDO with prepared statements.  You have to first establish a connection by constructing a PDO instance: [PDO::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) then using a prepared statement with [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

```
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT s.skill_Description, s.skill_PayRate from harris.SKILL s where s.skill_PayRate between ? and ?";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($start, $end));
```

If you are only supporting integer values which I would assume with using between, then you can make this easier and use something like:

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT s.skill_Description, s.skill_PayRate from harris.SKILL s where s.skill_PayRate between '.intval($start).' and '.intval($end);
$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
```

[intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) will force an integer value, or 0, on `$start` and `$end` to protect you from any invalid or malicious user input.

Comment: I always have an issue with these kind of answers. Is the OP's query an issue? Yes. Should he be using prepared statements? Yes. Is it your decision? No. I can see recommendations, but to provide an answer with a completely different API than the OP's when they are barely grasping the original question leaves me scratching me head.

Comment: @EternalHour I don't think it's a good idea to send the OP to use a query subject to SQL injections.  If the OP doesn't grasp the concept then I gave him a link to two places where he can find examples and descriptions.  There is no API included in the OP, so I included PDO, which supports prepared statements.  In my opinion, it is better to give him a safe example that he can learn from and may not understand than to give him a dangerous simple example.

Comment: Prepared statements aren't required to escape input, there are functions for that which are much easier to understand for a beginner.

Comment: @EternalHour, I gave the example for using intval(), but if you're using a string you should not rely on escape functions.  It is pretty common knowledge to make use of prepared statements as much as possible when using user input.  SQL injections are a major concern with code on SO and the web today.

Comment: We have to "answer the question in the scope of the question", and anything else is "advice". There is too fine a line for things like this to not be "advice". What next, change users poorly named variables to camel case, or answer their PHP question in another language because the result would be more secure to use? What if they cannot use PDO or Mysqli? Not enough time to learn it, not able to learn as spent weeks getting this far? Their server/company/client wont allow it? Again, anything outside the scope of the question should be "advice" (and in this case is certainly good advice!)

Comment: You guys need to slow down, @Devon can only make an educated guess on what DBA the OP is using. Props for `PDO`, but you just need to stick to the scope of the question -> `"how do i format the end of the select statement and the the line below it incorporating the two variable start and end?"` You supply that concatenated string and offered your advice. Good answer.

Comment: @James: camel case has no impact on security.  An SQL injection could lead to a database leak or destruction.  I think that is an important difference between a standard and blatant security issue.  Is it not better to learn the right way than to learn the wrong way then learn the hard way?

Comment: You're thinking too linear - my point was, we cannot use "opinion" to dictate what the OP may or may not want outside the scope of the question. Of course camel case is not security, but arguably readability is just as important as security when you have 100 files with 500 lines of code in each. That would be another presumption, and opinion, outside the scope of the question. I wasn't being funny, just that you need to answer the question, then give advice. As I said, it's good advice and the OP should take it/use it if possible. :)

Comment: @James I understand what you're saying but I respectfully disagree.  I think security is 100x more important than readability and I think the Fortune 500 companies that have major database hacks would agree.

Comment: On face value, yes, security is more important. Again, my point is, in either case, the OP didn't ask if their variables are well written or if their code is secure, or about SQL injections, or how to use PDO. They asked for a fix on *their* code. IMO, it should be a direct answer, then advice. I most certainly don't disagree with your sentiments though - they should switch while they are learning and obviously not far on with `mysql_` yet.

Comment: @James, I see your point but I think as* more experienced programmers, we should speak up and make it known about the security issues in the code and NOT post or condone code subject to security issues. Otherwise future users will visit this page, not aware of SQL injections, grab the correctly marked answer with the security issue in place and thus make their web site vulnerable to attack.

Comment: I agree, but in my eyes the "speak up as experienced programmers" is the "advice after the direct answer". I suppose what you are saying is it's better to not give the direct answer at all, and give OP and public one they should have for their benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach this.

Use a drop down list so that you can control the input by the user (change the values as needed).

**HTML:**

```
<form action="payScale.php" method="POST">
    <option name="range">
        <select value="a">20,000-30,000</select>
        <select value="b">30,001-40,000</select>
        <select value="c">40,001-50,000</select>
        <select value="d">50,001-60,000</select>
    </option>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
//verify that the $_POST value is not empty//
if (!empty($_POST['range']) {
    $range_value = $_POST['range'];
    //put salaries into array and select the correct value//
    if ($range_value == "a") {
        $start = 20000;
        $end = 30000;
    } elseif ($range_value == "b") {
        $start = 30001;
        $end = 40000;
    } elseif ($range_value == "c") {
        $start = 40001;
        $end = 50000;
    } elseif ($range_value == "d") {
        $start = 50001;
        $end = 60000;
    } else {
        echo "no matching salary range";
        exit;
    }

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT s.skill_Description, s.skill_PayRate 
              FROM harris.SKILL s 
              WHERE s.skill_PayRate BETWEEN $start AND $end";

    //your SQL query here//

} else {
    echo "Please select a salary range";
    exit;
}
```

Keep in mind that for this code to work your `skill_PayRate` needs to be `INT`. In your script however, you'll want to handle the output differently such as redirecting back to the form or something. It's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define interval with `Between`:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT s.skill_Description, s.skill_PayRate from harris.SKILL s where s.skill_PayRate between '$start' and '$end'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT s.skill_Description, s.skill_PayRate from harris.SKILL s where s.skill_PayRate between '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start))."' and '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end))."'";
```

i would suggest you ditch this technique and use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Not a bad idea to format/force a date using `date` and `strtotime` but I doubt payRate is supposed to be a date field.